# How to write an ECL launch configuration for a university cluster?

Tags: hpcc-ecl, hpcc

I have been working with a local cluster for some time, but now I need to expand my work and use a university cluster. I have written a JSON file for the ECL launch configuration, but I am unsure if it is correct or not. Here is the configuration I have written:

```
// Default ECL Launch Configuration
{
    "name": "university.us-hpccsystems-dev.azure.lnrsg.io:8010",
    "type": "ecl",
    "request": "launch",
    "protocol": "http",
    "serverAddress": "university.us-hpccsystems-dev.azure.lnrsg.io:8010",
    "port": 8010,
    "path": "",
    "targetCluster": "hthor",
    "rejectUnauthorized": true,
    "resultLimit": 100,
    "timeoutSecs": 60,
    "user": "user",  
    "password": "pass"
}
Please note that the username and password used in the configuration are dummy values.
```

I would appreciate any assistance in verifying if this configuration is correct for connecting to the university cluster. Additionally, if any modifications or additions are necessary, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like you are good to go. Remember that the "name" can be anything you want and doesn't have to match the "serverAddress". Also, I prefer to set my "targetCluster" to "thor". Happy coding!